# How do you Record physical file downloads, or a percentage of a file download?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to record every time a registered user clicks a link and downloads a file from a site. At the moment I am recording every time the link is pressed however this provides no information on if the file is **actually physically downloaded**? and moreover a download percentage if the file is not fully downloaded.

Does anyone know how I would go about recording a **physical download**?

Is this possible? If not through PHP Javascript/Jquery? I am quite lost, all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

link

```
<a href="download.php">download</a>
```

file

```
security/user check - record to database....
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefile.pdf"');
readfile('somefile.pdf');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to 100% guarantee that you will collect every clickinfo is to remove all of the files-to-download to a folder outside of the webroot. Then, any request to any file whatsoever has to be first processed and read to you by a php script which you can have logging the requests.

Essentially what you have above but, moving the files so they can't be executed/downloaded without using that php script first.

As for percentage, there are some libraries that you can install to mod your Apache for this. I don't know any particulars, though.